# File transfer in iphone with xmpp

Tags: iphone, xmpp

Hello Friend ,
             I am facing a problem regarding to XMPP in iphone . I want to transfer a file one id to other id but i have no any idea what type format use for file transfer . In this project  , i am using openfire on server and text chat work proper this time.

Please help for file transfer

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to interoperate with other people, you need to read these XEPs:

- [XEP-0095: Stream Initiation](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0095.html)
- [XEP-0096: SI File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html)
- [XEP-0065: SOCKS5 Bytestreams](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html)
- [XEP-0047: In-Band Bytestreams](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html)

Comment: thanx joe for your reply . joe i have any idea what type use this file .

Comment: have you any example in iphone regarding to file transfer ?

Comment: I almost added "before you ask, no there is no sample code.  Please read the specs and write it yourself", but I had hoped that was prematurely snarky.